# Strictly blank application uri in kohana route

Tags: php, routes, kohana

I'm trying to make a route rule to make my request to the main page in kohana. It's sth of this kind: http://my_site/
And got into trouble here. In docs they write i can make this or that, lots of variants, but no example for mine. Simply saying if i try to do this way

```
Route::set('main/index', '')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

then if i write Route::get('main/index')->uri() on page http://my_site/hi i get a link to the same page. If i do it this way

```
Route::set('main/index', null)
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

No result again, uri callback should have a valid value.
In official manual they suggest this variant

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

But i need a rule with a strict match i.e. just http://my_site/, not `http://my_site/(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))` 
Is there a way to help me out from this without rewriting Route class?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Route::get('main/index')->uri()` returns a relative uri, which in this case would be an empty string. What you want to do is use the `url` method of the `Route` class: `Route::url('main/index')`. This will give you an url that has gone through `Url::site` as well.

Comment: Thanx a lot. That's where my mistake is

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::set('main/index', '')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Works just for for me if I make sure that route is set before any other route that may match an empty uri. Routes are checked for a match in the order they are added.

If you want to know what if your route was matched (on a development server) you can set the default controller to a non-existing one like 'bogus'. Then Kohana wil throw a Http_Exception_404 and the exception handler will serve you an error page. (Turn on kohana errors if it does not.) On that page click on the 'arguments' link of the first trace of the stack trace. You should then see something like the following:

```
object Request(18) {
    ...snip...
    protected _route => object Route(5) {
        protected _callback => NULL
        protected _uri => string(0) ""
        protected _regex => array(0) 
        protected _defaults => array(1) (
            "controller" => string(5) "bogus" // the non-existing bogus controller default
        )
        protected _route_regex => string(6) "#^$#uD"
    }
    ...snip...
}
```

I got the above by placing the following route before I add any other route (which could match that uri too):

```
Route::set('main/index', '')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'bogus',
    ));
```

Also make sure no other route uses the 'main/index' name as it will overwrite the older one. Actually, I just took a look at the code of [Route::uri()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Route#uri) and guess what. Static routes (routes that have no '<' or '(' in them) should return the current url. Since an empty string is a static route the result Route::uri of that route would always be only the host. Which suggests me you are overriding the 'main/index' route assuming the uri was set to an empty string.

Also when using a NULL as the uri for a route it is assumed it came from the cache and you end up whith an empty route when it did not came from the cache.

Comment: Nope, i can't override it, because it's the only defined route i have. I guess i'll take a closer look at the source code, it seems tricky

Comment: Could it be a modules adds a route? Module's init.php gets includes during Kohana::modules() which get called before your Route::set().